# Not repeating one column value which is same against all other values in table - MVC view issue

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a tricky problem, not able to make out how to get out of it.

I have a requirement where I need to show my MVC view in a tabular form as below:

**Invoice Number**            **ProductName**
111                                  TV

      
                                 Music Player

      
                                 Laptop


112                                  Washing machine

113                                  CD Player

The idea is to NOT repeat the **Invoice number** if the products list fall into the same **Invoice Number**.

The simple foreach like one below repeats the Invoice number  :(

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceNumber)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
    </td>

</tr>
```

}

I can change the model as per my requirement.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: If you change it to a for x loop you can compare against the previous item in the collection.

Comment: Can you help me with some quick sample..

Answer (score 1):

This is not complete example but you have to do following way to solve your problem.

```
@{
   var previousItem = "";
}
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @if(previousItem != item.InvoiceNumber) 
        {
        previousItem = item.InvoiceNumber.ToString();
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceNumber)
        }

    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
    </td>

</tr>
}
```

Comment: this will only work if the items in Model are sorted by Invoice Number

Comment: Worked like a charm. I was thinking to change the model itself. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: @rajeem_cariazo They would have to be anyway to get the effect the OP wants.

Comment: Rajeem. Youa are right. My model is getting the data in the same format. But Yes, there is a chance of what you are talking about..

Answer (score 1):

The best way to think about this, is not how do you keep from repeating, but shape your view model to be like that to begin with.

For example, your model should be...

```
var model = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>();
```

then you can do...

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
<tr>
     <td> @item.Key </td>

     <td>
     @foreach(var product in item.Value)
     {
          @product<br/>
     }
     </td>
<tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq, you can group the items:

```
@foreach (var group in Model.GroupBy(x => x.InvoiceNumber)) {
<!-- first group item -->
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => group.First().InvoiceNumber)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => group.First().ProductName)
    </td>

</tr>
foreach(var item in group.Skip(1)){
<tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
    </td>

</tr>
}}
```

Or as single row alternative:

```
@foreach (var group in Model.GroupBy(x => x.InvoiceNumber)) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => group.Key)
    </td>
    <td>
        foreach(var item in group){
            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)</p>
        }
    </td>

</tr>
}
```

I admit, this is probably overkill for this example, but I guess it's nice to see different approaches.